# If $P$ is a set of probability measures, is there a probability measure s.t. $A$ is a $\mu$-null set iff $A$ is a $\nu$-null set for all $\nu\in P$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal P$ be a collection of probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$. Can we construct a probability measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ such that $A\subseteq\mathcal A$ is a $\mu$-null set if and only if $A$ is a $\operatorname P$-null set for every $P\in\mathcal P$?

Comment: it depend on $\mathcal P$. If $\mathcal P$ has just one probability measure, then yes, otherwise, it's not so easy. Take for example $\mathcal P=\{\delta _x\mid x\in \mathbb R\}$ (where $\delta _x$ is the dirac measure at $x$), then I don't think that such a $\mu$ can be constructed...

Comment: To elaborate on above comment $\delta_x << \mu$ implies $\mu \{x\} >0$ and this can only happen for countably many $x$.

Comment: If $\mathcal{P}$ is countable, then $\sum_{k \ge 1} 2^{-k} P_k$ is such a measure (where $\{P_k\}$ is an ordering of $\mathcal{P}$). This of course gives a condition under which you could get the result for uncountable $\mathcal{P}$ - if there is a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ such that every $P \in \mathcal{P}$ is a.c. with respect to $\nu,$ then decomposing $\nu$ into countably many pieces, normalising them, and then stitching together like above would work.